# lets encrypt certificate only accepted for root path

Tags: node.js, express, certificate, lets-encrypt

I've installed a certificate using Let's Encrypt Certbot. The site is reachable and connection is secure.

Say the site is `www.xxxyyy.xyz` but any route in there `www.xxxyyy.xyz/route` jumps to non-secure connection, and the site closes. Any idea what could be the problem?

The way I linked the certificate on an express server is the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = require('./app');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/twotravelers.xyz/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/twotravelers.xyz/fullchain.pem'),
};

var portSecure = '443';
var port = '80';

var httpsServer = https.createServer(/*options,*/ app).listen(portSecure, function(){
  console.log("https at port" + portSecure);
});

var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){
console.log('http at port'+port)
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. For reading paths I was using:

```
fs.readFileSync('<relativePath>/file')
```

When running the app on the server, I set up a service, and this changes the working directory to root `/`.
We can either add the absolute path:

```
fs.readFileSync('<absolutePath>/file')
```

Or add a `workingDirectory` to the service file (which is what I did).

That was messing the path to certificates and other directories.

---

Probably the best option is to `npm install dotenv` and control the behavior with environmental variables.